# get count of leading zeros in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create a select query that computes the number of leading zeros from a bit-operation in mysql? I would need to compare this to a threshold and return the results.
The Select-Query would be called very often, but i think that every SQL-based solution is better than our current strategy of loading everything into memory and then doing it in java.

example of the functionality:

`unsigned INT with the value 1 -> 31, since there 32 bits and the rightmost is set
unsigned INT with the value 0x0C000000 -> 4, there are 4 zero bits from the highest order to the first set`

I can then compare the result to a threshold an only get the ones above the threshold.

Pseudocode example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE numberOfLeadingZeros(data.data XOR parameter) >= threshold;
```

Comment: Pls provide some sample data and expected results because I'm not realky clear on what you really would like to achive here.

Comment: updated with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but please take a look at @viraptor's suggestion:

`SELECT * FROM data WHERE (32 - LENGTH(BIN(data))) >= threshold`

This just converts the integer into a binary string without the leading zeros. So if you subtract the length of this string from 32 you got the amount of leading zeros in the number.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e56c31/2

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution will not use any indexes. An index on `x` cannot be changed to the index on `BIN(x)`. You'll do a full table scan every time this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the counting of zeros, and just compare to a threshold. For example you know how many leading 0s are in 32-bit value `2`. Anything with fewer 0s will be `>2` and anything with more 0s will be `<2`.

So for your solution, instead of doing query `number_of_zeros(x) >= threshold` do a query for `x < value_with_threshold_leading_zeros`. (the value being `2^(31-number_of_zeros)`)